# Как использовать Spring контроллер без JSP?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jsp

Поставили задачу, написать задание с использованием Spring контроллера (Простая форма ввода сообщения, сохранения, вывода сообщения и т.д.) Но когда я сказал, что напишу на JSP - мне сказали, что это не уместно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне использовать контроллер без применения JSP? Я еще слаб в Spring, возможно как-нибудь можно controller использовать в обычной html странице? (Технологии которые использовать буду: Ajax, js, css, html, java, spring, hibarnate, maven сборка)
p.s. Все гайды и вопросы гуглу на тему spring приводят к созданию на Джава сервер странице.

Comment: Так-же убедительная просьба, если скидываете ссылку, пожалуйста - прикрепите вырезку ответа на данный вопрос.

Comment: Не понимаю в чём у вас проблема. Контроллеру не важно, кто именно отправляет ему запрос. Просто кладёте в проект обычную html-страницу вместо jsp, в атрибуте action формы прописываете адрес контроллера и всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Spring MVC. JSP вроде как довольно старая технология, когда в файле html страницы пишется java-код. Шаблонные html-файлы, заполняемые данными (генерирующимися на сервере) - это не JSP (а сложилось ощущение, что вы эти понятия смешиваете).

Поэтому продолжайте смотреть гайды по Spring MVC и выполняйте задание.